# Is there a way to set up a tor-ap and be able to turn tor routing off when needed?

Tags: raspbian, iptables, accessibility

I recently turned my raspberry pi into an AP and am wanting to follow the directions here https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview. However, after reading the section here https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/install-tor I see that iptables are set up to route all traffic through tor which would make being able to turn off tor access impossible. My question is , is there a way to accomplish being able to turn off tor and have unencrypted access to the internet via the AP when needed?

Thanks

Comment: So are you looking for something such as a bash script that you could run that would modify iptable settings to route directly to the client and to not use Tor?

Comment: If that's what is the best way to accomplish this then , yes, I am. I too thought a bash script that modifies iptable settings would be the answer here but am hoping that there is a more "elegant" (for lack of a better word) method.

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for? A webpage to modify settings? A physical button?

Comment: Eventually a webpage would be nice. But whether the button on the webpage is used to execute a script or something else is what I'm having a problem with.

Comment: I do not understand where your confusion lies, if you know that what you want is a webserver, iptables has a code binding for almost every language imaginable, so just chose a language your comfortable with and look up how to interface with iptables.